# Multiple email server on one domain

Tags: server, web-hosting, webmail, namecheap, email-spec

please How can I configure MX record to work for both google emails and webmail on the same domain? currently my webmail emails can only send emails but won't be able to receive emails because of the google MX record I have added. I will be expecting your feedback. thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this might be more applicable to https://serverfault.com/ but likely you will need to add more detail. See their https://serverfault.com/help for how to enrich your question with the needed details.

Comment: What do you mean by **webmail**? If you mean a URL to access your mail hosts inboxes, you would typically configure a CNAME and not an MX resource record. Edit your question to clarify what you are trying to accomplish, the vendor/software involved. Note that sending and receiving emails are different items requiring different configurations. MX resource records are used to determine the host to send emails to. Also, consider moving your question to Server Fault as this is not the best forum for this type of question.